# Traversing a Z3Context using the z3.scala.dsl API

Tags: scala, latex, z3

I'm using the scala^Z3 tool for a small library that (among other things) prints the constraints of a `Z3Context` in latex format. While it's possible to traverse the `Z3AST` and latex-ify the expressions by string comparison, it would be much nicer to use the object structure of the `z3.scala.dsl` package. Is there a way to obtain a `z3.scala.dsl.Tree` from a `Z3AST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that the DSL is currently "write only", in that you can use it to create trees and ship them to Z3 but not to read them back.

The standard way to read Z3 trees is to use [`getASTKind`](https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3/blob/master/src/main/scala/z3/scala/Z3Context.scala#L760) and [`getDeclKind`](https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3/blob/master/src/main/scala/z3/scala/Z3Context.scala#L774) from `Z3Context`. The classes that represent the results are [`Z3ASTKind`](https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3/blob/master/src/main/scala/z3/scala/Z3ASTKind.scala) and [`Z3DeclKind`](https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3/blob/master/src/main/scala/z3/scala/Z3DeclKind.scala) respectively. (Since most trees are applications, the latter is where most of the information is).

Comment: Ah, that's much better than what I was trying to do :-) So for flexibility I'm developing two latex transforms: one prints the original DSL tree, the other prints from the `Z3Context` using `getASTKind` and `getDeclKind`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the way to do this is create the original constraints using `z3.scala.dsl`, then add each constraint using `Z3Context.assertCnstr (tree: Tree[BoolSort])`. This way I have the whole DSL tree for easy transformation to latex. For some reason the examples on the scala^Z3 website assemble the AST without using the DSL at all, so this alternative wasn't obvious.